# colab is crashing while using keras.utils.to_categorical

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train neural network to indentify the colors. But issue is that when i use keras.utils.to_categorical for OneHotEncoding of color names, the colab is crashing and restarting. I tried this around 20 to 25 times but same problem persist.
Please help me

Answer (score 1):

May the data is not stored in a matrix or ma ythe numebr of categories is very high

Comment: Yes, number of categories are 58

Comment: it think that is a lot

Comment: so, how to deal with this problem?

Comment: do you have any solution for that

Comment: you can use for xample embedding sine the colors are expressed as words